# Getting timestamp of events(watch) in micro seconds in GKE

Tags: kubernetes

VirtualBox:~# kubectl get ep  -o custom-columns=Creation:.metadata.creationTimestamp,Labels:.metadata.labels,name:.metadata.name,Endpoints:.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip,"LastTrigger:.metadata.annotations.endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time" --watch

```
Creation               Labels                           name                    Endpoints                           LastTrigger
2020-02-17T08:51:44Z   <none>                           kubernetes              35.185.33.116                       <none>
2020-04-16T14:36:44Z   map[run:meghha-dashboard]        meghha-dashboard        <none>                              <none>
2020-04-28T16:43:03Z   map[run:meghha-dashboard-main]   meghha-dashboard-main   10.32.1.26                          <none>
2020-07-08T13:50:05Z   map[name:mongo]                  mongodb-service         <none>                              2020-07-08T13:50:05Z
2020-07-18T14:00:12Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx                10.32.2.88,10.32.2.91,10.32.3.178   2020-07-23T13:36:06Z
2020-07-19T13:28:13Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx1               10.32.2.88,10.32.2.91,10.32.3.178   2020-07-23T13:36:06Z
2020-07-19T13:28:13Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx1               10.32.2.88,10.32.3.178              2020-07-23T14:57:46Z
2020-07-18T14:00:12Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx                10.32.2.88,10.32.3.178              2020-07-23T14:57:46Z
2020-07-18T14:00:12Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx                10.32.2.88,10.32.2.91,10.32.3.178   2020-07-23T14:57:47Z
2020-07-19T13:28:13Z   map[run:my-nginx]                my-nginx1               10.32.2.88,10.32.2.91,10.32.3.178   2020-07-23T14:57:47Z
```

The timestamp of LastTrigger is in seconds.
Is there any way to get the timestamps in micro seconds in GKE cluster?
Any configuration settings?

Comment: Any one, who can answer ?

Comment: I think this parameter is hard-coded according to RFC 3339 date-time string and not configurable.

Comment: Nops. For business and mission critical systems, the time stamps has to be in micro seconds to take some decisions. K8 should provide the timestamp in micro seconds.
There could be thousands of messages at the same second, how to differentiate them and important is to check the difference of time in between events to discard the packets and take similar decisions.

Comment: Is there any way to get the time stamps in micro seconds for end points add/removal from Kubelet itself ??